# Please correct this QueryStringParameter

Tags: html, asp.net, sqldatasource

```
<td"><%#Eval("RegNo")%></td>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server"
      ConnectionString="<%$ cn%>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT * WHERE RegNo=@reg "> 
         <SelectParameters> 
             <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="reg" QueryStringField="<%#Eval("RegNo")%>" Type="String" />
         </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to pass a value(regno) from table to the select query

Comment: what you are looking for is a escape character. Try to google and use that. or you can use like this `QueryStringField='<%#Eval("RegNo")%>'`

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you intend to do. You should provide a more detailed description and possibly explain the problem precisely. So very little is understood.

Comment: i want to pass a value from the table to the select query